# few threads putting objects in a queue and main thread reads the queue

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

my question is 
I have a data say of 1000 records. i want 3 threads that process this data like 
thread1 from record 1 to 300, thread2 from 301 to 600 and so on. one thread can make a request and fetch 50 records at a time and create a object and put it in a queue.
Main thread will simultaneously read data from queue.
how can i do this.
i am new to threading.
i need some examples in code.
Below is the code, the problem i am facing is that recordRead variable tells the starting point from where the thread should start reading the records. 
But how can i set different value for each thread e.g for thread1 it should be 0 and recordsToRead should be 300 and for thread2, recordRead should be 300 and recordsToRead to be 300+300=600 and for last thread it should be 600 and upto the end. 
pagesize=50
pagesize,recordRead and recordToRead are all variables that belong to main class and main thread.

```
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads);
    while(nThreads > 0) {
        nThreads--;
        service.execute(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                do {
                    int respCode = 0;
                    int RecordsToRead = div;
                    JSONObject jsObj = new JSONObject();
                    jsObj.put("pagesize", pageSize);
                    jsObj.put("start", recordsRead);
                    jsObj.put("searchinternalid", searchInternalId);

                    try {
                        boolean status = req.invoke(jsObj); 
                        respCode = req.getResponseCode();

                    } catch (Exception e) {         
                        req.reset();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return true;
                    }
                    JSONObject jsResp = req.getResponseJson();
                    //here jsResp will be added to ArrayBlockingQueue.

                    req.reset();
                }while(!isError && !isMaxLimit && recordsRead < RecordsToRead);

            }

        });
    }
```

After this loop will be the code of main thread reading the queue.
how can i set recordsRead and recordToread for all threads.

Comment: You pretty much wrote how you do it. Is there any question here?

Comment: This question does not fit the StackOverflow's rules because it's too broad and will attract only opinion based answers (so expect it to be closed). Please, go to the: http://stackoverflow.com/help, then read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Start coding, that's how code gets done. If you get stuck, you can come back here with a _specific_ question.

Comment: You can google "producer consumer multithreading" to get started with some code examples.

Comment: Hi i posted the snippet of my code with a specific problem. Please look at it and advice.